# Mysql like to match pattern at end of string

Tags: mysql

I have the following strings in the following pattern in a table in my db:

```
this_is_my_string_tester1
this_is_my_string_mystring2
this_is_my_string_greatstring
```

I am trying to match all strings that start with a specific pattern split by underscores i.e.`this_is_my_string_` and then a wildcard final section

Unfortunately there is an added complication where some strings like the following:

```
this_is_my_string_tester1_yet_more_text
this_is_my_string_mystring2_more_text
this_is_my_string_greatstring_more
```

Therefore taking the following as examples:

```
this_is_my_string_tester1
this_is_my_string_mystring2
this_is_my_string_greatstring
this_is_my_string_tester1_yet_more_text
this_is_my_string_mystring2_more_text
this_is_my_string_greatstring_more
```

I am trying to have returned:

```
this_is_my_string_tester1
this_is_my_string_mystring2
this_is_my_string_greatstring
```

I have no idea how to do this with a like statement.  Is this possible if so how?

EDIT

There is one final complication:

```
 this_is_my_string
```

needs to be supplied as a list i.e in

```
(this_is_my_string,  this_is_my_amazing_string, this_is_another_amazing_string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM atable WHERE afield REGEXP 'this_is_my_string_[a-z]+'
```

It might be faster if you have an index on afield and do

```
SELECT * FROM atable WHERE afield REGEXP 'this_is_my_string_[a-z]+'
                     AND afield LIKE 'this_is_my_string_%'
```

---

***After edit of question:***

Either

```
SELECT * FROM atable
WHERE afield REGEXP '(this_is_my_string|this_is_my_amazing_string)_[a-z]+'
```

or maybe you want something like having a table with the prefixes:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable AS t,
    prefixes AS p
WHERE afield REGEXP CONCAT(p.prefix, '_[a-z]+')
```

*As by the reference documentation this should **not** be possible, as a **pattern** (string literal) is required. Give it a try nevertheless.*
There the answer of @KayNelson with LIKE (?) and INSTR might do instead of REGEXP.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt realise i can use regex in mysql!  There is one further complication that i need to account for.  I shall edit the question

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE strings LIKE 'this_is_my_string_%' AND instr(Replace(strings,"this_is_my_string_",""),"_") = 0;
```

It checks if more _ occurs after replacing the standard "this_is_my_string_"